# Find the dimension of $\ker(T)$ by first identifying a basis for the vector space $\ker(T)$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $T:V \rightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. The kernel of $T$, denoted by $\ker(T)$, is the set of all vectors in $V$ that are mapped by $T$ to $0\in W$.

That is, $\ker(T) = \{v \in V \mid T(v) = 0\}$.

It can be shown that $\ker(T)$ is a vector subspace of $V$, but you don’t have to verify that.

Now, let $W$ be the vector space of all symmetric $2$ by $2$ matrices.

Moreover, let $T$ be the linear transformation $T: W \rightarrow \textbf{P}_{2}(\textbf{R})$ defined by
\begin{align*}
T\begin{bmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{bmatrix} = (a - b) + (b - c)x + (c - a)x^{2}
\end{align*}
Find the dimension of $\ker(T)$ by first identifying a basis for the vector space $\ker(T)$.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Comment: Dear @John, welcome to the MSE! It is advisable to show some work before posting a question in this website. Could you please exhibit your attempts made so far?

Comment: Really sorry user1337. I will do that next time. This time I was really stuck and had no idea where to begin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix} \in \ker(T)$. Then, we must have $a-b=b-c=c-a=0$ (all coefficients of the polynomial must vanish). This means $a=b=c$. We have shown that the elements of the kernel are exactly the matrices with equal coefficients.

A basis for $\ker(T)$ is, for example, $\left\{ 
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1\\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}$, because every matrix with equal coefficients may be obtained by multiplying  this particular one by some real number

Comment: Thanks, Jandro. Can you please explain why can we let A=\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\
b & c
\end{pmatrix} be in kernel of T?

Comment: Well, you start assuming that a general symmetric matrix belongs to the kernel of T and then you show that it must have equal coefficients. So basically you have proved that every element of $\ker(T)$ has coefficients $a=b=c$

Comment: But, how do you verify that the assumption is right? I am still not understanding how can you assume that to start?

Comment: Imagine you need to prove that $A=B$, where $A$ and $B$ are sets (In our problem $A$ is the kernel of T and $B$ is the set of all 2×2 matrices with equal coefficients). To do so, you let $x$ be an element of $A$ (so you assume for $x$ all the properties an element of $A$ has; in our problem, since the element is in the kernel of $T$, we assume that $T(x)=0$) and you show that then it also belongs to $B$ (in our problem, that means prove that all coefficients are equal, since this is the condition for an element to belong to $B$). Now, you should also prove the other inclusion

Comment: that means, show that every element of $B$ is in $A$, but in our problem this is obvious, since every matrix with equal coefficients maps to the 0 polynomial (just take its image by $T$ using its definition)